# How to calculate numbers with large exponents

Tags: python, python-3.x, largenumber

I was writing a program where I need to calculate insanely huge numbers.

```
    k = int(input())
    print(int((2**k)*5 % (10**9 + 7))
```

Here, k being of the orders of 10<sup>9</sup>
As expected, this was rather slow( taking upto 5 seconds to calculate) whereas my program needs to finish computing in 1 second.
After a little research online I found a function pow(), and by writing

```
     p = 10**9 + 7
     print(int(pow(2, k- 1,p)*10))
```

This works fine for small numbers but messes up at large numbers. I can understand why that is happening( because this isn't essentially what I want to calculate and the modulus operation with such a large number doesn't affect the calculation with small values of k).

I also found libraries like gmpy2 and numpy but I don't know how to use them since I'm just a beginner with python. 

So how can I write an expression for what I want to calculate and which works fast enough and doesn't err at large numbers too?

Comment: can you provide an example of `k`

Comment: 1, 2, 1000000000. any positive integer not larger than 10^9

Comment: how about `int(pow(2,k)*5 % (pow(10,9) + 7))`

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't improve the speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can optimize your operation by passing the number you want to take modulus from as the third argument of builtin [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) and multiplying the result by 5

```
def func(k):

    x = pow(2, k, pow(10,9) + 7) * 5
    return int(x)
```